# Powershell Remove-Item versus cmd rd /s /q "path"

Tags: powershell

I want to use cmd rd /s /q from powershell but also make sure to run it only if the path exists. If the path doesn't exist, I want to skip the command. The best case solution Is to run cmd rd only for existing files, but currently, I check the existing path through if clause which I want to get rid of.
I am also thinking of using Remove-Item but I know for one is that Remove-Item can throw path too long exception.
I want to understand where all these both can behave differently(performance maybe?)
rd in powershell is simply an alias for Remove-Item.

Any solution for powershell v3?
Any param we can pass in cmd rd that skips if file is missing?

Comment: You may read about [common paramters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1). Especially `-ErrorAction` ...

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
Remove-Item "C:\temp\ttt" -Recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

-Recurse option is equivalent to /s
-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue dont throw error if path doestn exists